# Post File to SharePoint from APEX

Tags: apex, integration, callout, blob, sharepoint

I am using EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart approach to create a file in Sharepoint from Salesforce.
[EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart](https://github.com/muenzpraeger/salesforce-einstein-vision-apex/blob/master/src/classes/EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.cls)

And consuming it in my below method, with this approach files are creating but it is corrupted.

```
public static void fileUploadCallout(string idStr) {        
    List<contentversion> cvList = new List<contentversion>();
    cvList = [select id, title, ContentDocumentId, FileExtension, versionData from contentversion where Id = :idStr limit 1];
    if(!cvList.isEmpty())     
    {
        string fileName = cvList[0].Id;
        if(cvList[0].FileExtension!=null && cvList[0].FileExtension!='') {
            fileName = fileName + '.' + cvList[0].FileExtension;  
        }  
        //callout ePOR service
        string contentType = EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.GetContentType();
        
        //  Compose the form
        string form64 = '';
        form64 += EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBoundary();
        form64 += EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBlobBodyParameter('file', EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cvList[0].versionData), fileName);
        
        blob formBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(form64);
        string contentLength = string.valueOf(formBlob.size());
        
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('callout:Sharepoint/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'/sites/SalesforceFiles/Shared%20Documents/Test1\')/Files/add(url=\''+fileName+'\',overwrite=true)');
        req.setBodyAsBlob(formBlob);
        req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', contentLength);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        Http http =new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    }
}
```

There was one more approach I used as below, with that Files were creating but if we upload PNG file then its content was distorted and colors were fading. For PDF files few blocks themselves were removed. But at least something was visible.

```
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:Sharepoint/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'/sites/SalesforceFiles/Shared%20Documents/Test\')/Files/add(url=\''+fileName+'\',overwrite=true)');
req.setBodyAsBlob(fileContent); // this is blob file content
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/octet-stream');
req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(req.getBodyAsBlob().size()));
req.setMethod('POST');      
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

I also tried the approach mentioned at [Upload_Document](https://github.com/Docparser/Docparser-Apex/blob/master/upload_document.apx) but that also have same issues(Posting incomplete pdf/PNG files)

[image: ActualFile]
[image: FileOnSharepointAfterUpload]

Comment: Did you change you content-type and check? instead of `req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/octet-stream');` can you use `req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');` 

Based on https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well but still uploaded file content is not complete